# Cut command does not appear to be working

Tags: bash, parsing, cut

I'm piping a command to `cut` and nothing appears to be happening.

The output of the command looks like this:

```
     Name    File Info     OS
     11      FileName1     OS1
     12      FileName2     OS2
     13      FileName3     OS3
```

I'm trying to extract column 1,2 from all rows (starting with row 2) using the following:

`my_command | cut -f1,2` and the output is exactly the same as the original.

Comment: The `cut` command takes the field delimiter quite literally. If you have multiple consecutive spaces or tabs, it considers each one a delimiter of an empty field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cut doen't behave well with multiple spaces as a delimiter. Use awk instead

```
mycommand | awk 'NR>1{print $1,$2}'
```

Answer (score 3):

use tr -s to convert repeating spaces into single space. Now cut can be used where single space is delimiter seperating columns.

```
mycommand | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f1,2
```

Answer (score 3):

If multiple spaces are used for a delimiter and the column positions are fixed, you would use column numbers with cut:

```
mycommand | cut -c1-27
```

Or you could lose the front spaces with:

```
mycommand | cut -c5-27
```

This will work even if your fields have embedded spaces. The `awk` method will fail if you have embedded spaces in your fields.

Comment: Nice one. I wasn't aware that you can cut by character count.